# Loop isn't working for my Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

I have a setup where it favourites and retweets a specific tweet. For some reason, the code works for the favourites however retweets do not. Can anyone see the issue?

```
$method = 'statuses/retweet/'.$url[3];
$amt = "26";
$sub = rand(1,3);
$amt1 = $amt-$sub;

if($_POST['favorite'] == "true" || $_POST['favorite'] == "1"){
 for ($x1=1; $x1<=$amt1; $x1++)
   {
$content = $connection[$x1]->post('favorites/create', array('id' => $url[3]));  
}
}

if($_POST['retweet'] == "true" || $_POST['retweet'] == "1"){
for ($x2=1; $x2<=$amt; $x2++)
   {
$content = twitteroauth_row('statuses/retweet/'.$url[3], $connection[$x2]->post($method), $connection[$x2]->http_code);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried declaring

```
$amt = 26
```

instead of

```
$amt="26"
```

EDIT:

```
for ($x2=1; $x2<=amt; $x2++)
   {
$content = twitteroauth_row('statuses/retweet/'.$url[3], $connection[$x2]->post($method), $connection[$x2]->http_code);
}
```

you have used `amt` instead of `$amt` in the loop condition

Comment: Yes, and it the favourites work, however the retweets do not.

Comment: I fixed the $amt -- however am still having the same problem where it retweets maybe 3-4 times, when it should retweet around 20+.

Comment: @user2970029 i dont know if that might have to do something with the twitter api, the code seems fine now

Comment: How can you explain that favourites is working however the retweets is not? That's rather upsetting.

Comment: @user2970029 i sincerely suspect if there is a limitation in the api, is it always retweeting 3 times or 4 times only?

Comment: For some reason it just started doing this. Before it worked flawlessly.